# Mask the specified format?

Tags: javascript

I want to mask only specified format.

Format: `(123)(12)(1234)`; it shouldn’t mask `(123)(123)(1234)`

Output: `(###)(##)(1234)`

I am using this script:

```
console.log(str.replace(/\b\(\d{3}\)\(\d{2}\)(\d{4})\b/g, '(###)(##)$1'));
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: You capture the last set of digits, but forgot the escaped parentheses. `(\d{4})` should be `\((\d{4})\)`.

Comment: @Xufox Is this statement correct str.replace(/\b\(\d{3}\)\(\d{2}\)\((\d{4})\)\b/g,'(###)(##)$1');

Answer (score 0):

No need for any capture groups. Try using lookahead for the four digits instead, and make sure to escape literal parentheses with `\(`:

```
\(\d{3}\)\(\d{2}\)(?=\(\d{4})
```

```js
const mask = str => str.replace(/\(\d{3}\)\(\d{2}\)(?=\(\d{4}\))/g, '(###)(##)')
console.log(mask('(123)(123)(1234)'))
console.log(mask('(123)(12)(1234)'))
console.log(mask('(123)(12)(12345) and (123)(12)(12345) and (123(12)(1234)'));
```

Comment: this my string var str = '(123)(12)(12345) and (123)(12)(12345) and (123(12)(1234) '; and iam receving output: (###)(##)(1234) and (###)(##)(12345) and (123(12)(1234)

Comment: It sounds like you don't want any of those to be replaced at all? Also, unbalanced parentheses won't be parsed properly, what do you want in those situations?